# What is the equalievent of transfer() in zksync

Tags: zksync

I have a payable nft mint contract that send ETH fee to owner, when calling `mint()` function I recieve

```
Error function_selector = 0x, data = 0x
```

tx -> https://goerli.explorer.zksync.io/tx/0x050aefbe633a218fcab3783d70ace7ac93be6c04db19ac70327216a62d1f0a03

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract TreeToken is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    // address for payment
    address payable public owner;
    // supply
    uint256 public supply;
        // mint start date
    uint256 public startMintDate;

    constructor(uint256 _supplyLimit, address owner_, uint256 _startMintDate) ERC721("TreeToken", "TREE") {
        supply = _supplyLimit;
        startMintDate = _startMintDate;
        owner = payable(owner_);
    }

    function mint() public payable returns (uint256) {
        // check price
        require(msg.value ==  0.001 ether, "Payment must be 0.001 ether");
        // check supply
        require(_tokenIds.current() < supply, "Supply limit reached");
        // check start date
        require(block.timestamp >= startMintDate, "Minting is not yet allowed");
        
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
        return newItemId;
    }

}
```

after I saw [this](https://medium.com/coinmonks/gemstoneido-contract-stuck-with-921-eth-an-analysis-of-why-transfer-does-not-work-on-zksync-era-d5a01807227d) I am pretty confused and do not know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract TreeToken is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    // address for payment
    address payable public owner;
    // supply
    uint256 private  supply;
        // mint start date
    uint256 private startMintDate;

    constructor(uint256 _supplyLimit, address owner_, uint256 _startMintDate) ERC721("TreeToken", "TREE") {
        supply = _supplyLimit;
        startMintDate = _startMintDate;
        owner = payable(owner_);
    }

    // mint function for 1 eth payment goes to owner, cannot more than supply

    function mint() public payable returns (uint256) {
        // check price
        require(msg.value == 1 ether, "Payment must be 1 ether");
        // check supply
        require(_tokenIds.current() < supply, "Supply limit reached");
        // check start date
        require(block.timestamp >= startMintDate, "Minting is not yet allowed");
       
        (bool success, ) = owner.call{value: msg.value}("");
        
        // Check if the call was successful
        require(success, "Ether transfer failed");        
         _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        return newItemId;
    }

}
```

Using low level call worked.